# When does implicit type conversion occur in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, implicit-conversion, bit-shift

Let's say we have the following code, meant to shift the bits of `a` to the left by `i` and replace  the `i` LSBs of `a` with the `i` MSBs of `b`

```
unsigned short a;
unsigned short b;
auto i = 4;

a = (a << i) | (b >> (16 - i));
```

This works as expected. Now, let's consider the situation where we want to be able to do this for *pairs of different types.* i.e. we want to shift the bits of `a` to the left by `i` and replace  the `i` LSBs of `a` with the `i` MSBs of `b`, except now we have no guarantee on the size of `a` and `b`, only that they are unsigned. Let's consider the case where the size of `a` is less than that of `b`

```
unsigned short a;
unsigned int b;
auto i = 4;

a = (a << i) | (b >> (32- i));
```

I'm worried about "[overshifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122512/what-happens-if-we-bitwise-shift-an-integer-more-than-its-size)" `a`. However, depending on when the promotion of `a` to `unsigned int` occurs, a value may or may not be an overshift. Consider a value of `i=24`. This would cause undefined behavior if the type conversion happens after the shift, however not before. Thus, my question is when type conversion in this case will occur? I suppose I could explicitly cast `a` to the larger type, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Nitpick: I think part of your code samples got cut off.

Comment: Hmm, there should be two blocks, each 4 lines.

Comment: Unclosed parentheses. Neither block will compile.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: you can always add an explicit cast, e.g. `(unitmax_t)a << i`.

Comment: [Implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

Comment: yes, the issue is I want to avoid having to determine which type is larger, a or b's, since I only want to cast to the larger type

Comment: Jesper's comment solved it. Not sure how I overlooked it. THanks

Comment: @BryceKille `uintmax_t` is guaranteed to be at least as large as either. You might also consider an `if constexpr`block that checks `sizeof`.

Comment: However, in practice, I’d probably insert a `static_assert` that the variable is wide enough.

Comment: So I am relatively new to C++ (as may already be obvious). I was under the impression that promoting it to the largest possible type would be wasteful.

Comment: Integral promotions of operands happen before applying an operator, so operators never see arguments smaller than `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant quote from the standard, [[expr.shift/1]](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/expr.shift#1):

> [...] The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. [...]

This means in your case that `a` will be promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) **before** doing the shift.

Note, that with current 32/64-bit compilers, the promoted type is `int`, not `unsigned int`. The promoted type is `unsigned int` only if `int` cannot represent the whole range of `unsigned short` (for example, this is true for old, 16-bit compilers, where `sizeof(int)` is 2, and `sizeof(short)==sizeof(int)`).