# Cost of conversion

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Let me first explain the motivation of the problem I will outline. I have a vector `v` of unsigned words with information stored in the bits as well as a word `w` of some possibly different unsigned type. I would like to put `len` bits from `v` into `w`, beginning at the `i`th LSB of `w`. For example, consider the case below where I have represented the words as bits just for the sake of explanation.

```
T1 w = 10110100;
vector<T2> v = [11, 00, 10, 01];
T1 len = 5;
T1 start = 2;
T1 dst_digits = 8;
T1 src_digits = 2;

10110100 -> 10111100 -> 10001100 -> 11001100
```

It is clear that we will need to iterate through `v` and add bits to `w` one word at a time. One way to do this is the following

```
template<class T>
T _blend(T a, T b, T start, T len) {
    // Replaces len bits of a by the ones of b starting at start
}

auto it = std::begin(v);
while (len > 0) {
    w = _blend(w, 
               (T1) ((T1) *first) << start), 
               start,
               std::min(len, src_digits)
               );
    start += std::min(len, src_digits);
    ++first;
    len -= std::min(len, src_digits);
}
```

I am fairly new to C++, and the code above is simplified code, but the main idea stands. I have this working currently as well. However, I find the `(T1) ((T1) *first) << start)` ugly. If I don't include the first cast, though, the shift operation will be promoted to `int` or `long`, and then mismatch with the other types of `_blend`. If I don't include the second cast, I may [overshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122512/what-happens-if-we-bitwise-shift-an-integer-more-than-its-size) `*first` (in the case when `dst_digits > src_digits` and `start > src_digits`).

Now, my question is how costly are the two `(T1)` conversions? My guess is not nearly as costly as other things, like the `std::min` call or the other statements in the loop. I only ask simply because coming from Python, seeing something like `(T1) ((T1) *first) << start)` just looks plain unnatural, and I'm wondering if that's just a consequence of C++ with little to no overhead, and whether or not there is simply a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a little-endian system, an unsigned integer to unsigned integer cast is translated to zero or one instructions.

If there is a `uint64` in `rax` then casting to a `uint32` is basically a no-op. The compiler will just assume that the value is in `eax` (the least significant half of `rax`).

If there is a `uint32` in `eax` then casting to a `uint64` is just one very fast instruction. The compiler will zero extend (fill the most significant part with zeros) the value in `eax` and place the result in `rbx` with the `movzx` instruction.

Unsigned integer casts are the least of your concern during this operation. You might want to consider using `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset` as they will do this bit twiddling for you.